# SCCM Identify retired applications

Tags: sccm

One of our customer got hundreds of applications which we believe needs to be retired, so we would like to have an automated solution created which will allow us to confirm they can be retired. The script\query\tool will need to check deployments, dependencies, task sequences, devices that still require this version etc.
Has anyone run into the same requirement, please help ?

Comment: I've created such tool. I won't be able to provide you that. But yes, it's possible to create one. You will have to query DB for all applications, find out if it has any deployment. Query WMI to check if it's added as dependency to any other applucation. And so on. Let me know if you are stuck somewhere, we can help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the Config Manager PowerShell Module. The 'IsExpired' property of the CMApplication object indicates whether the application has been retired.

```
Get-CMApplication -Name $AppName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IsExpired
```

Once you understand the object and property, you could run a query where only applications are selected where the 'IsExpired' status is $true.

```
Get-CMApplication | Where-Object {$_.IsExpired -eq "$True"}
```

I'd recommend running this on a subset of applications first if you have a large repository.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, As mentioned in my question I need to check the application's deployments, dependencies, task sequences, devices that still require this version etc and the command you provided is the application expiry status.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry. I think it will be hard get the information you want. However, I've done something similar where I wanted to identify whether the application was a dependency for another object. I did this using the 'NumberOfDependentDTs' and 'NumberOfDependentTS' properties. I think if you wanted to return what those dependencies were, you'd have to use SQL.